# Redis on Spark:Task not serializable

Tags: scala, redis, apache-spark

We use Redis on Spark to cache our key-value pairs.This is the code:

```
import com.redis.RedisClient
val r = new RedisClient("192.168.1.101", 6379)
val perhit = perhitFile.map(x => {
    val arr = x.split(" ")
    val readId = arr(0).toInt
    val refId = arr(1).toInt
    val start = arr(2).toInt
    val end = arr(3).toInt
    val refStr = r.hmget("refStr", refId).get(refId).split(",")(1)
    val readStr = r.hmget("readStr", readId).get(readId)
    val realend = if(end > refStr.length - 1) refStr.length - 1 else end
    val refOneStr = refStr.substring(start, realend)
      (readStr, refOneStr, refId, start, realend, readId)
 })
```

But compiler gave me feedback like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:270)
    at com.ynu.App$.main(App.scala:511)
    at com.ynu.App.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.redis.RedisClient
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    ... 12 more
```

Could somebody tell me how to serialize the data get from Redis.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Spark, the functions on `RDD`s (like `map` here) are serialized and send to the executors for processing. This implies that all elements contained within those operations should be serializable.

The Redis connection here is not serializable as it opens TCP connections to the target DB that are bound to the machine where it's created.

The solution is to create those connections on the executors, in the local execution context. There're few ways to do that. Two that pop to mind are:

- `rdd.mapPartitions`: lets you process a whole partition at once, and therefore amortize the cost of creating connections)
- Singleton connection managers: Create the connection once per executor

`mapPartitions` is easier as all it requires is a small change to the program structure:

```
val perhit = perhitFile.mapPartitions{partition => 
    val r = new RedisClient("192.168.1.101", 6379) // create the connection in the context of the mapPartition operation
    val res = partition.map{ x =>
        ...
        val refStr = r.hmget(...) // use r to process the local data
    }
    r.close // take care of resources
    res
}
```

A singleton connection manager can be modeled with an object that holds a lazy reference to a connection (note: a mutable ref will also work).

```
object RedisConnection extends Serializable {
   lazy val conn: RedisClient = new RedisClient("192.168.1.101", 6379)
}
```

This object can then be used to instantiate 1 connection per worker JVM and is used as a `Serializable` object in an operation closure.

```
val perhit = perhitFile.map{x => 
    val param = f(x)
    val refStr = RedisConnection.conn.hmget(...) // use RedisConnection to get a connection to the local data
    }
}
```

The advantage of using the singleton object is less overhead as connections are created only once by JVM (as opposed to 1 per RDD partition)

There're also some disadvantages:

- cleanup of connections is tricky (shutdown hook/timers)
- one must ensure thread-safety of shared resources

(*) code provided for illustration purposes. Not compiled or tested.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I use this library https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis. It haven't a method named "close", instead, it is "disconnect".I've no idea if it works. Could you tell me which library you are using now to deal with Redis data?

Comment: Plus 1 for the Singleton solution. Can you give an example on how to manage the closing of the connection?

Comment: @Sohaib given this is a VM-bound object, you'll need to register a shutdown hook to cleanly close connections.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to serialize the *client*. You have one `RedisClient`, `r`, that you're trying to use inside the `map` that will be run across different cluster nodes. Either get the data you want out of redis separately before doing a cluster task, or create the client individually for each cluster task *inside* your `map` block (perhaps by using `mapPartitions` rather than `map`, as creating a new redis client for each individual row is probably a bad idea).

Comment: Thank you for answering, but could you tell me how to use mapPartitions in this situation?

Comment: Call `mapPartitions` passing a block that accepts an iterable (as you can see from the signature of `mapPartitions`), creates the `RedisClient` *inside the block*, and then uses it to `map` the `Iterable` as you were doing. The point is that the `RedisClient` gets created inside the processing for a single partition. What did you try and where did you get stuck?