# static map sent to worker nodes before getting populated in afterPropertiesSet()

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have used spark streaming with spring. I have a repository implementation where I have maintained a static cache. This cache is populated in afterPropertiesSet() method of the class. Now, when I am trying to access this cache from the driver node (that is, in rdd.forEach()), I am getting the populated cache. But when I am trying to access this cache from the worker nodes (that is, in mapping phase), I am getting an empty cache.

So, is the method afterPropertiesSet() called after sending the class instance to the worker node? If that is so, then how should I populate this cache so that I get it in the worker nodes as well?

I have provided the code below to give an idea of what I have done -

This is the repository implementation class:

```
@Service("hbaseRepository")
@Data
@Scope(SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class HbaseRepositoryImpl implements HbaseRepository, InitializingBean  {

private static Map<Class<?>, HBaseEntityMetaInfo> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Autowired
private IoTStreamProps props;

private static Tuple4<String, String, String, String> serializableProps;

@Autowired
private EntityAnnotationProcessor<HBaseEntityMetaInfo> annotationProcessor;

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Log.info("hbase repository meta cache is going populate");
        EntityScan scan = Optional.ofNullable(HbaseConfig.class.getAnnotation(EntityScan.class)).orElseThrow(() -> new IoTException("EntityScan or packages attribute is missing"));
        cache.putAll(annotationProcessor.process(scan.basePackage()));
        serializableProps = new Tuple4<String, String, String, String>(props.getHbaseMasterUrl(), props.getZookeeperQuorum(), props.getHbaseZkPort(), props.getHbaseTableSanityCheck());
    }

public static Map<Class<?>, HBaseEntityMetaInfo> getCache() {
        return cache;
    }

}
```

So, when I call HbaseRepositoryImpl.getCache() from the driver node, I am getting the populated cache, but if call the same from the worker nodes (in map phase), I am getting an empty cache.

Comment: IMHO: "static" hell

Comment: I'm far past from Spring, but I would assume that you need a Spring  context to wire all those services. How is that Spring context created on the executors?  (BTW, this is so easy in Scala that seeing this amount of  boilerplate almost makes me cry)

Comment: Well, I think spring context is not at all created on the executors. On the driver node, spring context is being executed and cache is getting populated from the afterPropertiesSet() method call. But on the worker nodes, the cache is getting re-created with blank map and hence, it does not possess the populated values (as was done in the driver node). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There're two things: the `static Map` definition and the Spring Context used to magically populate it. The `static Map` will be recreated and initialized in each executor, but there's no Spring magic to populate it, so it will be empty. Here's a similar example of the same kind of use case (in scala): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006517/redis-on-sparktask-not-serializable/28024183#28024183